# Grails domain class id inheritance

Tags: grails, abstraction, grails-domain-class

I have four domain classes having common properties, `transID, createdDate` wherein the `transID` is typed `int` and mapped as the Primary Key of the table. By rule of abstraction, we seperate the common properties/attributes to an abstract class then let the child class (which in my case the four domain classes I have) inherit them or `extends` it.

In my abstract class contains the two properties `transID, createdDate` but since the `transID` is set to be the Primary Key of the four child classes I have formatted this mapping inside the abstract class.

```
static mapping = {
  id generator: 'increment',
     name: 'transID',
     column: 'transID',
     type: int
}
```

I have no errors in running the project then, but when I check the tables on the dbconsole, I can't see the four tables with relation to the four domain class yet I only see the abstract class having the properties of the first child.

Is there a way to abstract the id of the mentioned domain classes or I have to mapped it to the child classes rather than having it in the abstract class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default GORM uses table per class hierarchy, so you will have just one table - if you want one table per subclass - you can configure so using GORM DSL - see [Inheritance in gorm](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM)

But be careful before you use table per subclass excessively.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But it still doesn't solve the problem. I still having the same error.

Comment: Actually, I'm still having the same error, having only one of the four tables created in database

Comment: But have u configured table persubclass inheritance strategy !!